# Internet through SSH +proxy

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a server which is connected to the Internet through a proxy and another PC, without internet connection but with access to this server through SSH. And what is needed - connect the PC to the internet using SSH. I've found that `ssh -2 -C -D 4567 username@example.tld` creates a SOCKS4/5 proxy at `127.0.0.1:4567`, and it seems to be working. But in my situation, 
i'd need to chain one more proxy: the one through which the server connects to the internet. I haven't found any possibility to specify a chain of proxies, so what are the alternatives? What's the (easiest?) way to do this?

Comment: Is this the layout you are trying to describe? `Your PC` -> `an SSH server` -> `a proxy` -> `teh interwebs` . Is the proxy a regular internet proxy or another SSH server?

Comment: Yes, it's true. The proxy is a regular HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell SSH to forward all requests to your local port 8080 over the other pc to the proxy-server:

```
ssh -N -L 8080:<proxy-server-ip>:<proxy-service-port> username@example.tld
```

Now set your local proxy-settings to `localhost` port `8080`